# Topology for MobileFirst Foundation Server V8 on a two-cluster two-node WebSphere Network Deployment Environment

Tags: mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

What environment topology would you suggest to set up an IBM  MobileFirst Foundation Server V8 on a WebSphere two clusters and two nodes, one node for each cluster network deployment environment?

Answer (score 0):

With MobileFirst Foundation Server V8, you have two options to choose.

1. If  you want admin console on each node , you can follow FARM      
topology, as designated in https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/es/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/production/topologies/#server-farm-topology 
2. Rather than FARM topology, you can also have a server runtime on each of the node, and admin console on one of the nodes and let the admin console manages both runtimes, https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/es/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/production/topologies/#websphere-application-server-network-deployment-topologies